# I need to send multiple emails from a spreadsheet in Google Sheets but with a message that comes from multiple columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Okay so I have got a list of 150 emails in my first column, and I need to send emails out to all 150 independently. However, those 150 rows have 6 columns worth of information beside them (Name, Age, Size, Colour of clothing etc.).

Is it possible to use Google App Scripts to achieve this if so, could anyone support me with either a link to some code or send me some.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to retrive all data in a 2D array using "getValues", then you need to loop the array with a for loop. In the loop you will get the [i] data and fill a string or html template and then send email. ([i][0] will be the email, [i][1] the name...).

Use this code to start...

```
function myFunction() {
  var array = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();      
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    var loopEmail = array[i][0];
    var loopName = array[i][1];
    var loopAge = array[i][2];
    var loopSize = array[i][3];
    var loopColour = array[i][4];
    var loopField1 = array[i][5];
    var loopField2 = array[i][6];        
    text = "Hey " + loopName + ", your age is " + loopAge + " and you size is...";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(loopEmail, "Subject", text);
  } 
}
```

#### Note:

- If you have header on your sheet remember to start i=1 not i=0.

Comment: Notes: Use better names, I used this so you could understand that the variables are changing in the loop. If you have header on your sheet remeber to start i=1 not i=0.

Comment: Thank you so much!